# I think this was an honest mistake: did I handle it correctly?

Tags: discussion

A new user seems to have mistakenly posted [an answer as an edit to the question he was answering](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3152/24204).  I cut and pasted his answer as I was rejecting the edit (which Lee also voted to reject) and put it here.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56780/24204

I left a note in the text that it will be deleted by me in 48 hours.  I also flagged my answer so that a mod could contact Jonathan and allow him to correct his mistake, which I think was an honest mistake made by pushing the wrong button in the user interface.

Was this fair or foul, on my part?

Comment: It's not a great answer so I wouldn't have bothered, but I guess there's no harm in what you've done.

Comment: Mod's have a tool to convert answers into edits (as that's a frequent mistake) but off the top of my head I don't recall seeing the opposite tool. Nor do I ever recall bumping into this before. I guess I wouldn't have bothered and/or posted it as CW without the meta description content, but no harm no foul I guess.

Comment: @Caleb If the poster does not return, I'll delete the answer.  I had a few "hit the wrong button" episodes when I first started using SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like going the extra mile to me (it would have been perfectly reasonable just to reject and move on) - good on you.

Comment: And now the hilarity arrives -- someone up-voted the answer, which is (as I tried to break down the wall of text) rather hard to follow.  It is now deleted.